# What does it mean for a Category to have equalizers or/and pullbacks?

Tags: terminology, category-theory

I know the definitions of what pullbacks and equalizars mean, but I don't know what it means that a given category $\mathfrak C$ has pullbacks or equalizers.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that every pair of parallel morphisms has an equalizer / every pair of morphisms with common target has a pullback.